# What is this weird BLUETECH camera?

Tags: camera-identification, equipment-identification

I've had this weird camera laying around for three years now. Here are some pictures of it.

[image: Front]
[image: Back]
[image: Side 1]
[image: Side 2 - 1]
[image: Side 2 - 2]

I am looking for its users manual. But I don't know its name ("BLUETECH" I assume!) or model. And I cannot find it anywhere in the internet.

Have any one seen this camera before? What's its name? And how can I use it? And what type is that connector? And where can I find a cable to connect it to my PC?

Comment: It looks like a copy of an older model GoPro. Does it have a memory card slot? That could let you use it without a cable.

Comment: Hi @vclaw ! No, it doesn't have a memory card slot. Only that weird port.

Comment: Is there any kind of identifying information inside the battery compartment or on the inside of the battery cover?

Comment: Hi Michael Clark. Unfortunately, [**here**](http://imgur.com/a/kssQr) is what the battery compartment looks like.

Comment: The weird port is a form of mini usb. You might still find it on "universal" USB cables with a star-shaped set of plugs on the end if you've lost the cable. It was used on proper cameras as well - 15 years ago.

Comment: Thanks Chris H. This tells a lot. I might be able to solder a USB cable from  the inside.

Comment: Don't solder a cable to something where you don't even know if it works - an inexpertly soldered cable can give you all kinds of headaches if it is an USB 2.x device....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to be a generic/rebranded version of a [DigiGR8 100k keychain camera/webcam](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ETCA8C).  It also appears on ebay at a surprising prices considering the underwhelming performance of the camera.

A few years back I got a visually similar unit out of a claw machine, I think it was branded "Bell & Howl" (yes, spelled like that).  It was 'toy' grade, and I found it to be of no real use, even when I got it to work.

The reviews at Amazon tell a similar story.  Although it seems to have been put to use as a webcam for use with Skype.

I also remember the 'manual' was a card double-folded to match the size of the camera.  It had very basic 'engrish' instructions on plugging the battery in and the USB-mini cord that came with it, nothing about drivers or anything.  There was a mini 'business card form-factor' cd that came in the blister pack that had a software package and drivers.  I could not find a source for those files, and that CD is long since gone.

A google search for [DIGIGR8 CD-10B4](https://www.google.com/search?q=DIGIGR8%20CD-10B4&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) came up with a number of distributor websites, listing it as "Generic" so its likely produced with the branding the company ordering the units wants.  If that is the case, the original manufacturer is likely not in business anymore.  I did not see the Bluetech name in the search results I surveyed.

Highlights from the Amazon page give the unit these stats:

- 100K pixel CMOS Sensor
- 16 MB internal memory
- 352 x 288 pixels image resolution(CIF)
- 176 x 144 pixels image resolution (QCIF)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've got something with similar specs (different shape) and this description sounds right. Mine is no longer supported on Windows (though "supported" was always an exaggeration) but works out of the box on Linux. Image quality is atrocious - it seemed to be a way of using up the sensors left over from the first generation of camera phones, with a plastic lens. Mine is occasionally useful for monitoring tasks in webcam mode.